# How do create a python module for MySQL Workbench?

Tags: python, plugins, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a simple Python module for MySQL Workbench 5.1.17 SE however I cannot seem to register the module, that is, it is not displaying under the Plugins->Catalog menu.

The documentation appears to be rather weak at this time, the best I have found is [Python Scripting in Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org/?p=197). There isn't much in the way of instructions here.

How do I create and install a python module with MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chatted with one of the developers of MySQL Workbench via IRC and it turns out there were two problems:

1. I had to make sure my python script ended with *_grt.py so that it was recognized as a module.
2. There is a bug at least in version 5.1.17+ that prevents more than one python script module from being loaded. This has been fixed in a branch but has not yet made it into the stable release. The current workaround is to remove / delete any *.py modules you have in the following folders:

   - *\modules*
   - *C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\MySQL\Workbench\modules*